# First Data Zero Dollar pre-authorization as credit card verification

Tags: php, api, firstdata

Currently I have working Fosdick payment gateway (they are fulfillment place as well), but it looks like they do not authorize (or verify credit card up front) but do only simple CC checksum so it crates situations when orders were placed and Fosdick ended up with not valid credit card (out of funds, fake CC#, etc).

In that case I need to verify credit card before sending orders to Fosdick and what I have found, based on a First Data [documentation](https://firstdata.zendesk.com/entries/407571-First-Data-Global-Gateway-e4-Web-Service-API-Reference-Guide#3.2), I can use Zero Dollar Pre-Authorization.

Does anybody had similar situation and if so does First Data Zero Dollar Pre-Authorization works as a solution to verify credit card or run regular pre-authorization transaction on Firs Data?

Comment: It works great for me, however, I came here looking to see if there's a specific issue with Amex because we are having some sort of issue, but it appears to just be with Amex.